# How can I install rayshader on an AWS machine?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rcpparmadillo, rayshader

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few hours but I can't find any way to do it. The command that I have used is: install.packages("rayshader")

I have tried to install the 'rayshader' package on an AWS machine with an EC2 instance. The intention of this installation is to be able to run a make command for the auto creation of a RMD report containing 3D graphics from 'rayshader'.

The errors returned by the execution are as follows:

```
make: *** [RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo’
ERROR: dependencies ‘jpeg’, ‘RcppArmadillo’ are not available for package ‘rayimage’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rayimage’
ERROR: dependencies ‘raster’, ‘rayimage’, ‘RcppArmadillo’ are not available for package ‘rayshader’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rayshader’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpDWE73c/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("rayshader") :
  installation of package ‘jpeg’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("rayshader") :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("rayshader") :
  installation of package ‘rayimage’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("rayshader") :
  installation of package ‘rayshader’ had non-zero exit status
```

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first error is `ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’`, so try to get that one working first. What do you see if you try `install.packages("RcppArmadillo")`?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Gregor. I tried to do this step but the installation of RcppArmadillo was wrong. I attach the message:


...
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpmWN9I2/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RcppArmadillo") :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: You could try a command line install of that package, [like this](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/r-cran-rcpparmadillo)